# Changing state of checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart

i followed a many a tutorials on YT on how to change the state of my check box when i tap on it , but i found nothing seems to work , or every solution ive tried when i click on checkbox no change is rendered to show its been touched

```
class _ViewMealState extends ConsumerState<ViewMeal> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool check1 = false;
    bool check2 = false;
    bool check3 = false;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: (Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          
          CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(widget.documentSnapshot['Choice_1']),
              value: check1,
              onChanged: (newVal) {
                setState(() {
                  newVal = check1;
                });
              }),
          CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(widget.documentSnapshot['Choice_2']),
              value: check2,
              onChanged: (newVal) {
                setState(() {
                  newVal = check2;
                });
              }),
          CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(widget.documentSnapshot['Choice_3']),
              value: check3,
              onChanged: (newVal) {
                setState(() {
                  newVal = check3;
                });
              }),
        ])),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the assignment statement order wrong.

Instead of `newVal = check1`, you must do `check1 = newVal`. The way you currently have it changes the `newVal` parameter variable's value, rather than the value of `check1`.

Comment: also tried it this way still not sure why it gives the same problem ? I then tried to either make 'check1'  nullable or give 'newVal' a check operator (as require4d by editor) it still produced the same results ,neither seemed to be working